# Radiobutton validation in JSP

Tags: html, validation, jsp, radio-button

I'm trying to make a register form with radiobuttons like this

[image: msgErr sent by the validation]

and I validate the input on another `.jsp` file using the form

```
<form action="Controller/doRegister.jsp" method="post">
<table bgcolor="#000000" align="center" cellspacing="5px">
  <tr>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="rdo" id="gender_male" value="male"> Male
      <input type="radio" name="rdo" id="gender_female" value="female"> Female</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

with the validation

```
String userGender = request.getParameter("rdo");
if(userGender!="male"&&userGender!="female") 
  response.sendRedirect("../register.jsp?msgErr=Gender must be chosen "+userGender);
```

but when I tried the form I got an error message

> "Gender must be chosen"

even though I chose the radiobutton. When I think that maybe the `userGender` button didn't receive any value, I print the `userGender` and it shows "male". Please tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that you should use

```
if(!userGender.equals("male")&&!userGender.equals("female"))
```

Because we are not using '=' or '!=' for String comparison.

To avoid NullPointer, check if the userGender is null before you perform the comparison:

```
if(userGender!=null)
{
    if(!userGender.equals("male")&&!userGender.equals("female")) 
      response.sendRedirect("../register.jsp?msgErr=Gender must be chosen "+userGender);
}
```

Comment: The code worked when I use `.equals` and select one of the radiobutton. but now I got a new error when I didn't chose any. It says `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /ProjectLab/Controller/doRegister.jsp at line 24` 
where the 24th line is
`else if(!userGender.equals("male")&&!userGender.equals("female")) response.sendRedirect("../register.jsp?msgErr=Gender must be chosen");`
it also says `root cause`
`java.lang.NullPointerException`  

I print userGender only to see if it has a value or not

Comment: @Reynaldi please checkout the change in the answer, just do a simple NullPointerCheck before you continue with more stuff.

Comment: And finally the code is working fine, thank you. (I don't know why the comment textarea says to avoid comment such as "thanks")